# Is it possible to not create third table in hibernate mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using one to many and one to one relationships. I do not want to create a third table
[image: Image of table layouts and their joins]

Comment: just add `Student_ID` in `PHONE` table as a foreign key and it will work perfectly as it is standard for One to Many Relationships

Comment: 3rd table is used for `Many to many` relations

Answer (score 0):

**You only need two tables. Create table structure like this**

***STUDENT TABLE:***
STUDENT_ID,
STUDENT_NAME

***PHONE:***
PHONE_ID,
STUDENT_ID,
PHONE_TYPE,
PHONE_NUMBER